# how i can adjust Websphere to act non thread safe mode for web service

Tags: java, web-services, thread-safety

I have a web service (`JAX-WS`) deployed on `WAS7`, and it work fine, but per request, a new instance of my endpoint (web service class) instantiate.
I want to create only one instance and all request handled there.

Any idea? 
Thanks in advance, 
Alen.

Comment: why? what is the problem?

Comment: You want to keep up the state between requests?

Comment: for performance reasons.

Comment: No i donot want to keep up the state between requests